# Which ruby type does map to java.io.File in jruby?

Tags: java, jruby

I try to call [FSDirectory.open](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html)

```
FSDirectory.open(File.open('index', 'w+'))
NameError: no method 'open' for arguments (org.jruby.RubyFile) on Java::OrgApacheLuceneStore::FSDirectory
```

`String` gives a similar error.

Comment: `java.io.File`. If you want its methods, use it explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FSDirectory.open takes a java.io.File, which has no real equivalent in Ruby. Ruby's "File" represents an open file, while java.io.File simply represents a path. You should just use java.io.File in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
FSDirectory.open(java.io.File.new('index'))
```